# how to replace special character in mysql using REPLACE function

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, special-characters

I stuck in some serious problem with mysql.

In my database I have many records with xxx™ and i want to replace it with xxx©
i am using replace function in my query but it is not working but when i echo my query and run on phpmyadmin then it effects rows and replace correctly.

My database is Too big so i cant download and search and replace in any editor.

Below is my query :

```
$u="update category set name =replace(name,'xxx™','xxx©')";
and also tried with:
$u="update category set name =replace(name,'xxx&trade','xxx&copy;')";
```

Please help me out in this issue !!

Comment: So you mean that when you are running query in phpmyadmin directly then it is doing correct but through php mysql code its is not doing correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into converting the copyright/trademark symbol from and into an HTMLEntity in order to ease data transfer to the database.

Reference:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

© Copyright Symbol: `&#169;`

™ Trademark Symbol: `&#153;`

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `character set` of mysql and then you can run your query as your query contain special character:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8');
```

where `$conn` is your connection variable.

Hope this solves your query.